# How to do login with Facebook from 127.0.0.1 server?

Tags: flask, oauth

So I am following this tutorial to enable login with Facebook on my app that I am creating with Flask: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/oauth-authentication-with-flask-connect-to-google-twitter-and-facebook/

The tutorial says to use localhost:5000 as the server name. However, whenever I do that, and follow the steps of running the app, the page that shows up is simply a blank page.

So, I decided to get rid of the localhost:5000 as the server name and stuck to the default 127.0.0.1 server. When I do this, the page opens up perfectly and I see what I need to see on the starting page:
[image]

However, when I click connect to see if I am able to login, I see this[image]

I don't know what's going on.

Is this because I am using the 127.0.0.1 server? I have registered my app on Facebook developers and have included the CLIENT ID and CLIENT SECRET in my code. Yet, it doesn't seem to work. Can you please help?